# Can not load view from Custom Renderer Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am setting up cross platform app using xamarin forms, I have used this guide to use a hybrid webview, the purpose of this is to use openlayers maps, so, I can select markers, and return those markers to view and load list of those markers into a new view.

This is the guide I am using

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Javascript function is return markers information correctly to View.

**The problem is code below**:

```
hybridWebView.RegisterAction (data => DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Hello " + data, "OK"));

//I have changed this into this method, and created new function LoadSelectedLeads

hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => LoadSelectedLeads(data));

// I have used this await or without await too, both didn't work

public async void LoadSelectedLeads(String data)
{
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new SelectedLeads()));
}
```

The only issue I am facing its not loading the `SelectedLeads()` at all, it shows **error** this

> "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views xamarin forms"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You force it to run it on UI Thread:

```
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new SelectedLeads()));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied this out of some production code that I have, `await ((StartPage)Current.MainPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(page);` another way to say this would be `await YourNavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new SelectedLeads());` Try this along with and in addition to what Burno shows above.

Comment: I will try that too